# How can I receive location based reminders

Tags: webapp-rec

I love google calendar for sending me time-based reminders.  But sometimes I want to receive reminders based on my location rather than the current time.

For example if I want to remember to pick up a book I loaned to my sister I would like to add a item to a map that will alert me to grab the book then next time I am within 100 meters of her address.

any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a web app to me. Maybe a mobile app of some sort? I'll bet there's iPhone and Android apps that do just this, although I haven't looked.

Comment: When the Electronic Gadgets SE site goes public beta, I'd recommend asking there as this seems like a mobile question.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets

Comment: @Harlan, Aren't many mobile phone apps essential webapps? Example: foursquare, gowalla, yelp, google maps, gmail. http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/207/mobile-phone-web-app-related-questions-allowed

Comment: @rchern, thanks for the advice, I'll try that and link any answer they generate to this question ( or just migrate the question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with @rchern's comment about this being ideal for gadgets.stackexchange.com when it launches.

That being said, a number of iOS4-enabled iPhone apps will do this, notably the latest version of [Pocket Informant](http://pocketinformant.com/products_info.php?p_id=pocketinformant_iphone)

Comment: Pocket informant looks very promising.  Thanks 3rdparty.

Comment: I've only started playing with location-based task alerts in it (just bought it since it's on sale right now..)

They seem to work, although it depends on the GPS lock that the iPhone has - I'm also not totally sure how GPS services run in the background (or how accurate they are).  I wish it was a bit easier to set the location for an alert in PI (presently you have to tag it into a "context", which then has a location attached to it)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find an application that is tied into GPS and then have a device that stays on all the time.  I'm not currently aware of anything that does this though, but could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm allowing my self to point you to http://www.jellydo.com
It does location-based reminder based on your foursquare checkins.
I'm not sure that will help with your specific case, but i'm working on adding support for more services including twitter, google latitude, etc...
I'm also working making sure that we can use the GPS information of your iphone to help you.
Hope that helps. And if you have any feedback, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Locationizer for iPhone is the best Location based app I've tested.  It is easy to use, easy to shut off, and it won't kill your battery.